# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, pandas

I read this blog

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

And I think I'm so near to find the issue so can anyone help me to solve this according to this blog

```
This is my code.

from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(numpy_dataframe_train, train['adj_close_price'])
prediction=rf.predict(numpy_dataframe_test)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
idx = pd.date_range(test_data_start, test_data_end)
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(data=prediction[0:], index = idx, columns=['adj_close_price'])
predictions_df['adj_close_price'] = predictions_df['adj_close_price'].apply(np.int64)
predictions_df['adj_close_price'] = predictions_df['adj_close_price'] + 4500
predictions_df['actual_value'] = test['adj_close_price']
predictions_df.columns = ['predicted_price', 'actual_price']
predictions_df.plot()
predictions_df['predicted_price'] = predictions_df['predicted_price'].apply(np.int64)
test['adj_close_price']=test['adj_close_price'].apply(np.int64)
#print(accuracy_score(test['adj_close_price'],predictions_df['predicted_price']))
print(rf.score(numpy_dataframe_train, train['adj_close_price']))
```

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace and error message as well?

Comment: <ipython-input-56-07c7103f8186>:19: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  test['adj_close_price']=test['adj_close_price'].apply(np.int64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a warning. I will suggest you to use higher and latest version of pandas.

You should assign like this:

```
test.loc[:, 'adj_close_price']=test['adj_close_price'].apply(np.int64)
```

or you can disable it by:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: I add this  "  test.loc[:, 'adj_close_price']=test['adj_close_price'].apply(np.int64) and now it was running from 1 hour :P

Comment: Yes, I know as you mentioned above. But the thing is I got 50% accuracy right now. and I think by solving this warning will increase this model accuracy up to 90%

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
predictions_df = predictions_df.assign(
        adj_close_price=predictions_df['adj_close_price'].apply(np.int64), 
        adj_close_price=predictions_df['adj_close_price'] + 4500,
        actual_value=test['adj_close_price'])
```